# Authorize.Net Integration on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize.net

The current version of the [Authorize.NET SDK](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet) is only compatible with older versions of ASP.NET Having mostly finished the app in ASP.NET Core, we would really not want to revert to an older version. All of their examples fall back to this SDK and are not very helpful. Need some help integrating their API into a ASP.NET Core app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet/issues/162) for .NET Core support, but it has not been addressed yet.

Since the SDK NuGet package doesn't support .NET Standard or any PCL that's compatible with Core, you'd need to either fork the SDK and adapt it to .NET Standard, or make direct calls to the Authorize.NET API.